# How do I use a protocol for an attribute that shows up after running a method?

Tags: python, python-typing

I am working on a package that intimately uses scikit-learn objects. I wanted to use a protocol to identify the interface for certain aspects of sklearn functionality. One example is that an object when the `fit` method is run gains an attribute called `feature_names_in_`. However, it does not exist before it is `fit`. How do I use structural typing here?

```
_TransformerSelf = TypeVar('_TransformerSelf', bound='TransformerMixin')

@runtime_checkable
class P(Protocol):
    # Causes error because it doesn't exist
    # at instantiation time.
    feature_names_in_: Sequence[str]  

    def fit(
        self: _TransformerSelf, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.DataFrame | None = None
    ) -> _TransformerSelf:
        ...
```

Comment: If the attribute does not exist, then you are _by definition_ dealing with a different type. What would make sense is if for example the attribute had some default value such as `None` before the `fit` method was called and thus the type was `Sequence[str] | None`. But _creating_ an attribute literally turns the object into one of a different type, which is why most type checkers would consider such an operation _not typesafe_.

Comment: Consider `class Foo:  x: int` `foo = Foo()` `foo.y = 3.14`. Even though that last assignment will work at runtime, it would not pass `mypy` instead yielding a `attr-defined` error. I am not aware of any typing construct that would express the intent to turn the object into one of a different type upon calling some method. If that method _returned_ another object, that would of course be trivial. Just annotate it with another protocol that extends the previous one. But the type checker will not view the _calling_ object any differently.

Comment: Got it — thank you! So to summarize I would create two types for sklearn transformers (despite the fact that there is no separate concept in their codebase): an unfit transformer protocol (no attributes) and a fit transformer protocol (has attributes). If this is the case, I will accept this an answer if you add it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Different attributes ⟺ different types

If the attribute does not exist, then you are *by definition* dealing with a different type. It would be a different story, if for example the `feature_names_in_` attribute had some *default* value such as `None` before the `fit` method was called and thus its type was `Sequence[str] | None`. But *creating* an attribute literally turns the object into one of a different type, which is why most type checkers would consider such an operation **not type safe**.

Consider the following:

```py
class Foo:
    x: int

foo = Foo()
foo.y = 3.14  # not type safe
```

Even though that last assignment *will work* at runtime, it would not pass a Mypy check, instead yielding an `attr-defined` error.

### Extend the return type

I am not aware of any typing construct that would express the intent to turn the object into one of a different type upon calling some method.

If that method returned another object, that would of course be trivial. We could just annotate it with another protocol that extends the previous one. But the type checker will **not** view the *calling* object any differently.

Example: (tested with `mypy==1.2.0`)

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Protocol, TypeAlias, runtime_checkable

import pandas as pd

DF: TypeAlias = pd.DataFrame


@runtime_checkable
class Transformer(Protocol):
    def fit(self, x: DF, y: DF | None = None) -> FitTransformer: ...


@runtime_checkable
class FitTransformer(Transformer, Protocol):
    feature_names_in_: Sequence[str]


t: Transformer
ft = t.fit(pd.DataFrame())
reveal_type(ft)  # Revealed type is "FitTransformer"
```

This may seem less elegant since technically `t` would be identical to `ft` after calling `fit` on an *actual* instance (not just the protocol) and thus have the `feature_names_in_` as well, but that will not be visible to a type checker.